# Create a schedule by the Schtask.exe

Tags: go, scheduled-tasks, exec

I try to create a schedule, but I always get the error (`exit status 0x80004005`) when I run the

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("schtasks.exe", "/Create",
        "/SC ONLOGON",
        "/TN MyTask",
    )
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Even if I run it with `administrator` privileges, I still get the same result.

How do I solve it, or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must put every parameter into separate array items, and you must add the /TR paramteter to specify which program it should run:

```
cmd := exec.Command("schtasks.exe", "/Create",
    "/SC",
    "ONLOGON",
    "/TN",
    "MyTask",
    "/TR",
    "calc.exe",
)
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

Comment: @carson, to maybe better explain the reasoning, you should note that the grouping of the command-line parameters (such as `/SC` and `/TN` of `schtasks`) with their argumen(s) exists only in your head; for the command-line parameter handling code implemented in a program which uses them, the parameters are merely an array of strings (in Windows it's more complicated but let's not digress), so when you call `schtasks` passing it `/SC ONLOGON`, as a single string, the parser there literally sees that complete string, but it knows of no parameter "/SC ONLOGON", literally…

Comment: @carson, …instead, when the parser encounters a parameter `/SC`, it knows that another parameter must follow (otherwise it's an error), and its literal value should be treated as the argument for `/SC`.